# Using “tr” command hides the working directory

Tags: command-line, unix, terminal

When I run the [`tr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) command in terminal as

```
tr -d text
```

My cursor performs a carriage return but the working directory line disappears. I cannot run commands afterwards unless I <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. What is happening here? It also works properly if I use quotes, but this is a matter of understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the man page:

```
-d Delete characters in string1 from the input.
```

You’re not giving it any input but the characters to delete so it is in a [REPL (read–eval–print loop) mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop). Try this so you can understand:

```
tr -d e
```

Then write `test` press enter and you’ll get `tst`.

You could use it this way:

```
echo "test" | tr -d e
```

And you’ll get `tst` and back to the prompt

Comment: Bonus point if you can tell me how to save once you're in that mode.

Comment: `tr -du e >> file.txt`

That will append to the file anything you do in the REPL mode.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now how do I grant bonus points? I didn't think this through.

Comment: I must object to the use of "REPL" here, what 'tr' is always doing  is simply reading a file, in the examples above that file is `stdin`, file descriptor 1, `<1` as no filename was given - the same happens when you pipe into tr. `CTRL`+`D` will tell tr there was an 'end of file'. Compare to typing `python` and the interactive prompted mode you get there.

Comment: More: http://www.tldp.org/guides.html, the Bash guides